# Retrieving information from database via a 'connecting table' (containing id's for other tables)?

Tags: java, sql, database

I've run into some trouble with my SQL coding, which I am using to manage a database through Java (by sending queries for the database to execute).

Our project's objective is to make a flight booking system, and in case, I want to get a hold of some Departure-objects that are related to a certain customer, by having searched for the customer via his/her email.

In our database, our Seat table has a foreign-key Id for both Departure (Which only contains time and date in the database) and Customer. My thought was to use these Id's to connect my search, ultimately connecting the Customer to the relevant Departure-information.

Here is my code as of now:

```
@Override
public ArrayList<Departure> getCustomerDepartures(String email)
{
    try
    {
        ArrayList<Departure> departures = new ArrayList<>();

        String query = "SELECT DISTINCT fr.DepartureLocation, fr.Destination, 
d.Date, d.Time FROM Departure d, Customer c, Seat s, FlightRoute fr WHERE
c.Id = s.CustomerId AND d.Id = s.DepartureId AND c.Email = ?;";
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setString(1, email);

        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()) {
            String departureLocation = rs.getString("DepartureLocation");
            String destination = rs.getString("Destination");
            int date = rs.getInt("Date");
            String time = rs.getString("Time");
            departures.add(new Departure(departureLocation, destination, date, time));
        }
        return departures;
    } catch (SQLException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Could not collect departure data, associated with customer.");
    }
    return null;
}
```

What I gain from this, when I try to display the options for departures in a `JList` in the GUI (Having made the `ArrayList` of Departure-objects into an Array of Departure-objects and an Array of Strings (For displaying the departure info)), is that it always gives me 9 different options in the `JList` (thus, the returned `ArrayList` contains 9 Departure-objects), with different values.

Comment: I think this question is more suitable for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table `FlightRoute` isn't joined to in your query properly, so you are getting a cross-product with it.  Add the appropriate join condition  (ie and `fr.something = s.something`)

Comment: That does make sense, yeah. I have a similar search elsewhere in my code where it lists departures based on certain search criteria, but in that instance, I don't have a d.FlightRouteId = Departure.Id condition either, and it seems to work perfectly, so I'm not sure if this is at least the only issue. Can you think of anything else? I'll try out your suggestion tomorrow, once I have the code on hand, and confirm this post, if it solves the issues I'm having.
Thanks for the reply. :)

Comment: Well, I entered the condition you suggested, and it does indeed seem to have made everything work as it should! Thanks a lot! :)